# Raspberry Pi CAD Files

Tags: hardware

I know the Pi schematic is available in pdf but my question is the Pi schematic available for any electronic cad software like Eagle?

Comment: I think you'll have to write it yourself. Is this for a college project or something?

Comment: They are meant to be open source; But no source of open sources has been given yet...

Comment: The more bad thing is, you can't find some text in the schematics using 'find | ^F'. Its annoying.

Answer (score 4):

Given the pictures and schematic in the PDF files and the complexity of the PCB board this was not likely drawn in Eagle CAD.

The blog suggests that the design was using Mentor Graphics Expedition software. Not free, quite professional.

[This thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1090) might shed some more light.

There are some designs for the physical dimensions including Sketchup 3D, Wavefront.obj and 3D-Studio.3d, for more [read here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=4402).